# Oracle Sql Union all error when creating new column

Tags: oracle, union-all

Good morning all.  Im having trouble combining 3 outputs together using a union all statement.  My query is below and Im getting an error saying ATTR is invalid.

Ideas?

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "ATTR": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"



SELECT
                "TOC_GENDER" as Attr_Type
                ,TOC_GENDER as Attr
                ,COUNT (DISTINCT CON_INDIVIDUAL_ID) AS UNIQ_INDIV_ID_CNT
                ,COUNT (DISTINCT TOC_DEALER_NO) AS UNIQ_DLR_CNT
FROM   zeta.Customer_table
GROUP BY Attr_Type, attr
union all
SELECT
                "TOC_HD_TARGET_SEGMENT" as Attr_Type
                ,TOC_HD_TARGET_SEGMENT as attr
                ,COUNT (DISTINCT CON_INDIVIDUAL_ID) AS UNIQ_INDIV_ID_CNT
                ,COUNT (DISTINCT TOC_DEALER_NO) AS UNIQ_DLR_CNT
FROM   zeta.Customer_table
GROUP BY Attr_Type, attr
union all
SELECT
                "TOL_POLK_COMPETITIVE_BRAND" as Attr_Type
                ,TOL_POLK_COMPETITIVE_BRAND as attr
                ,COUNT (DISTINCT CON_INDIVIDUAL_ID)      AS UNIQ_INDIV_ID_CNT
                ,COUNT (DISTINCT TOC_DEALER_NO)    AS UNIQ_DLR_CNT
FROM   zeta.Customer_table
GROUP BY Attr_Type, attr
ORDER BY Attr_Type, attr;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use aliases in `group by`. Change those to `group by TOC_GENDER`, etc.

In addition, `ORDER BY` can be tricky with `UNION` (and also can't use aliases). Either wrap the whole query in an outer `select` with the current `ORDER BY` clause or change it to `ORDER BY 1,2`.

---

To add a column with a static values, you need to use single quotes, rather than double quotes. Single quotes are use to demarcate a string, whereas double quotes are used to demarcate an identifier (such as a table name or column name).

As a column with a static string has a single value across the entire result set, it does not need to be included in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: That solved the error (thank you), but I was trying to create a  column called Attr_Type with the value 'TOC_Gender'. The next column Attr will have the actual values of TOC_Gender. Basically i want customer counts for different variables in my table.  Those variables all have multiple values, gender is male, female. Target segment has 6 values, etc.  Since the columns are all different i need to rename them the same but i need a way to know which belong to which columns.  Make sense?

Answer (score 3):

Don't group by the aliased name of the column:

```
SELECT
                "TOC_GENDER" as Attr_Type
                ,TOC_GENDER as Attr
                ,COUNT (DISTINCT CON_INDIVIDUAL_ID) AS UNIQ_INDIV_ID_CNT
                ,COUNT (DISTINCT TOC_DEALER_NO) AS UNIQ_DLR_CNT
FROM   zeta.Customer_table
GROUP BY Attr_Type, attr
```

should be

```
SELECT
                "TOC_GENDER" as Attr_Type
                ,TOC_GENDER as Attr
                ,COUNT (DISTINCT CON_INDIVIDUAL_ID) AS UNIQ_INDIV_ID_CNT
                ,COUNT (DISTINCT TOC_DEALER_NO) AS UNIQ_DLR_CNT
FROM   zeta.Customer_table
GROUP BY TOC_GENDER
```

Comment: There's not really any point in listing the same column twice in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @Allan - good point (didn't read carefully enough) - removed duplicated name